# Send mail with Laravel Lumen

Tags: laravel, email, lumen

I've a domain and an email address dedicated. I've a **SMTP** server provided by my domain. I'm asking myself if it's possible to send mail directly with this SMTP server without passing through API like MailGun (because, it's not free!), and how can I do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: If your server has Cpanel, you can see the configuration such as ip, port, username, and password.

Comment: So if I understand well, I juste need ton create a mail.php file into config folder and use it through the methods provided by Laravel (like create a class extends Mailable, a view and a route) ?